# third dimensional array remove duplicates php

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, php-7

How can I remove duplicate values from a third-dimensional array in PHP?

Example array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:92 [▼
      "id_product" => "12"
      "id_supplier" => "0"
      "id_manufacturer" => "2"
    ]
    1 => array:92 [▼
      "id_product" => "14"
      "id_supplier" => "0"
      "id_manufacturer" => "2"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:92 [▼
        "id_product" => "16"
        "id_supplier" => "0"
        "id_manufacturer" => "2"
    ]
    1 => array:92 [▼
        "id_product" => "14"
        "id_supplier" => "0"
        "id_manufacturer" => "2"
    ]
    ]
]
```

my expected array

```
 array:2 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:92 [▼
          "id_product" => "12"
          "id_supplier" => "0"
          "id_manufacturer" => "2"
        ]
        1 => array:92 [▼
          "id_product" => "14"
          "id_supplier" => "0"
          "id_manufacturer" => "2"
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:92 [▼
            "id_product" => "16"
            "id_supplier" => "0"
            "id_manufacturer" => "2"
        ]
    ]
 ]
```

and I try array_unique but still the same

```
$new_products = array_unique($accessories, SORT_REGULAR);
```

and I try many things ,many functions but still the same.

Comment: Is this a php array!? I think you can not have two element in array with same key

Comment: yes is a php array , and about the key I make a mistake when I write the question I fix it now

Comment: your array is not the same       "id_product" => "12"
      "id_supplier" => "0"
      "id_manufacturer" => "2"  and         "id_product" => "16"
        "id_supplier" => "0"
        "id_manufacturer" => "2"

Comment: I mean this         "id_product" => "16", and         "id_product" => "14",

Comment: is this a typo problem too?

Comment: I want to delete   "id_product" => "14","id_supplier" => "0","id_manufacturer" => "2" this where is the duplication

Comment: please add you expectation array to your question

Comment: ok , Done I add it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will do exactly what you want

```php
<?php

$input = [
    [
        [
        "id_product" => "12",
        "id_supplier" => "0",
        "id_manufacturer" => "2"
        ],
        [
        "id_product" => "14",
        "id_supplier" => "0",
        "id_manufacturer" => "2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "id_product" => "16",
            "id_supplier" => "0",
            "id_manufacturer" => "2"
        ],
        [
            "id_product" => "14",
            "id_supplier" => "0",
            "id_manufacturer" => "2"
        ]
    ]
];
$inputCopy = $input; 
$serializedData = [];
foreach ($input as $keyFirstLayer => $valueFirstLayer) {
    foreach ($valueFirstLayer as $keySecondLayer => $valueSecondLayer) {
        $serializedValueSecondLayer = serialize($valueSecondLayer);
        if (in_array($serializedValueSecondLayer, $serializedData)) {
            unset($inputCopy[$keyFirstLayer][$keySecondLayer]);
        } else {
            $serializedData[] = $serializedValueSecondLayer;
        }
    }
}

print_r($inputCopy);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_product] => 12
                    [id_supplier] => 0
                    [id_manufacturer] => 2
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id_product] => 14
                    [id_supplier] => 0
                    [id_manufacturer] => 2
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_product] => 16
                    [id_supplier] => 0
                    [id_manufacturer] => 2
                )
        )
)
```

I first go to the third layer with two foreach and then make a `$serializedData` array which contain the array of serialized elements and then try to unique the array with checking the element data with this array